# Using external ID in custom field as secondary as the secondary field in the instant search box

Tags: lightning, global-search

When I type a name in the [All] search box, the instant results dropdown list shows shortcuts to recent items as documented [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=search_lookup_config_lex.htm&type=5) and [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=basics_search_records_lex.htm&type=5). As documented [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=search_results_setup_lex.htm&type=5) and [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=search_instant_results.htm&type=5) is should be possible to specify which field you want to show as secondary field below the instant search result.

[image]

I have customized the search layout for System Administrators in Lightning Experience to show an external ID (which is a text field) as secondary item. I tried to make it the first filed but that gives me an error.

[image]

In turn, it is not working, the instant results still just show the default Related Account as secondary search field. What I am missing?

Ideally, I would like to get instant results by typing in the external ID, but it looks like this is not possible (or maybe just with Einstein)?

Comment: is the secondary field the _first_ field in the search layout as per doc?

Comment: @cropredy I tried, but I get: `Error: Name must be the first field in the search layout.` ?

Answer (score 0):

After having a similar use case, but for Account obj here is what I found.

The 1st record will be record name or record type (depending on your case - mine was Account name).

After reading a couple of times this article ''https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.search_lookup_faq_secondary_field_lex.htm&type=5 '', I understood that not every field can be ''captured'' by the system.

Long story short : you might be able to display a certain type of secondary field in the Global search other type of secondary field in the Lookup search.

My use case : in the Lookup search field I had to display an internal number and a country code. I created a formula text field that will catch and concatenate the field ''external id'' and ''country code''.
After I had the field created, I added it as secondary field in the page layout and now it works.

I hope it helps everybody else, since I am replying to a question from '20.

Comment: Thanks, it has been a while. I look into this as soon as I can.